# How to make a UI with movable windows by user

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a UI with different datagridviews with the ability of being moved by the user (click and drag).

I tried to wrap it in a panel and a toolstripcontainer but I couldn't find the way to make it movable.

Here is my UI at this moment. I just want to be able to move the datagridview clicking and dragging around my main window.

[image]

I think that I should wrap each of my datagridview in some kind of control that give me that possibility but I don't know which one. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to implement a Multiple Document Interface? There are lotsa tutorials out there, just take your time and google the one you like.

Comment: Should it be possible to change the columns, only or should they be placable freely in x and y? If the latter, you may want to investigate [MDI Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications).

Comment: how did you try it when using a panel? did you use the "drag" events?

Comment: what is supposed to happen when you drag the first datagridview to the last position, should they switch places? will the last go to the first position then?

Comment: Why you think this is a bad question?

Comment: I have thought about that but yes they should switch places Thank you @MongZhu

Comment: It is multiple document interface, I didn't know the correct word now I can find a tutorial. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Control.Draggable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Control.Draggable/) nuget package (sorce code [hear](https://github.com/intrueder/Control.Draggable)). Its quit simple, it lets you drag a control in its parent control. After you add the nuget package you enable dragging as follows:

```
dataGridView1.Draggable(true);
```